# How does return SUM() in spring data jpa

Tags: java

I am uning Spring boot with spring data jpa.

I've made repository that extends JpaRepository and I want to get SUM() of table results.

table schema is like

point

user_index, user_point

and query to get point total is

select SUM(user_point)
from point
where user_index = 1;

what is the best way to get this result?

I am considering to use native query, but I think to use JPA Repository is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the query you wrote? I believe jpa query does support sum operator

```
@Query(SELECT SUM(p.user_point) FROM point p WHERE p.user_index = :user_index)
float totalPointByUser(@Param("user_index") Long user_index)
```